# How do I build a reusable form in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

As a beginner, I would like to build a form with a few input fields and be able to reuse it in different pages. How can I build this with JavaScript/jQuery objects and be able to reuse it?

Let's call the object CustomerForm, and by calling a function `CustomerForm.submitInformation()`. I have no idea what syntax/structure looks like? I am familiar with jQuery/JavaScript but I have not built Javascript objects before. How can I do an AJAX post or a JSONP post to the server? How do you structure this differently for AJAX and JSONP?

Let's assume the form looks like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="foo" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="foo@moo.com" />
  <textarea name="comment">Whatever</textarea>
</form>
```

How do you submit this form with AJAX and/or JSONP? What do I need to do to create a form object and how do I use it in various pages?

So, I based on Nicholas's help, I am closer to getting the gist of this. I have created a Customer object,

In formload.js

```
Customer = {name: "", email: "", submitInformation: function(){
    var form = '<form name="input" action="submit_action.php" method="get">';
var label1 = '<label>Your&nbsp;Label:&nbsp;</label>';
var input1 = '<input type="text" name="name" value="foo" />';
var label2 = '<label>Your&nbsp;Second&nbsp;Label:&nbsp;</label>';
var input2 = '<input type="text" name="email" value="foo@moo.com" />';
var sub = '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
var killform = '</form>';
var br = '<br />';

$('body').append(form + label1+input1 + br + label2+input2 + br + sub + killform);

}}
```

In HTML view, customer.html

```
$(document).ready(){
    var customer1 = new Customer();
    customer1.username = customer1.input1.val();
    customer1.email = customer1.input2.val();
    customer1.getInformation();
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Create a function that builds the HTML you want, include this function on each page that you wish to use it.

Comment: Well, I know that, but what does this function look like? Can you share it in code?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Well I don't know how to do this, that's why I asked this question. I don't not necessarily need help on how to build the content of the HTML, but I need to know what to do in each page, what to include to make this function accessible? I am looking at how to design this simple problem in Javascript so that it is production ready

Comment: It's really frustrating for me when I post new questions and people downvote them without really answering my questions. Why is that necessary?

Comment: Perhaps starting in the help/FAQ sections would help answer that question http://stackoverflow.com/tour  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you cannot answer this question, please allow someone else to do it and not downvote it!

Comment: Good luck, now you earn -1 and a close vote from me.

Comment: Wow. I guess this is not a place where people can ask questions.

Comment: 1 sec. I'm answering now

Comment: That's because you ask 3 different questions, that each one of them is a whole page of instructions by itself. I suggest getting a good book of HTML, Javascript, and a server-side language of your choice. People love to answer here but they want to see effort and the question has to be focused...

Comment: In response, you'd probably want to utilize the `input2` for email, but essentially I don't see any reason that wouldn't work.

Comment: I've read books and watched countless tutorials. I've also signed up on Lynda.com and watched their video on Javascript objects. I understand what Javascript objects are and their patterns. However, I don't know how to apply it to this a real scenario. I just need more practice building objects on my own to get a better understanding of what Javascript objects mean.

Comment: ^ +1. We are not here to code for you, but if you have a specific question, we WILL answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you **could** just hard write it via jQuery, but this really isn't the best solution. If you are editing an `HTML` page, you should really include your form using `PHP` with an `include` of the appropriate document, or use some sort of `CMS` system (Wordpress? Joomla?) to import and reuse files.

Of course, you asked the question, so one way you could do it would be like so:

1. Keep your `submit_action.php` file stored on the same `domain` to avoid `CORS` issues.
2. Just write a hard-coded `append` to the `HTML` using `jQuery`.

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/nAQ3C/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('body').append('<form name="input" action="submit_action.php" method="get"><label>Your&nbsp;Label:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="name" value="foo" /><br /><label>Your&nbsp;Second&nbsp;Label:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="email" value="foo@moo.com" /><br /><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>');
});

/* Then just write your submission request with PHP, ASP, or whatever other service you'd like to use and upload that file as well */
```

*Note that `DOM` manipulation is possible, but should be minimalized as much as possible as it is much more stressful on the browser itself for the `client`.

---

#### Edit:

To reuse this for instance, you would have to save it as an external `js` file and just load it into the `head` of your `html` pages like so:

```
<head>
<script src="js/formload.js"></script>
</head>
```

And for the sake of readability, I've expanded it slightly:

http://jsfiddle.net/nAQ3C/3/

Where `formload.js` is equal to:

```
$(function() {
    var form = '<form name="input" action="submit_action.php" method="get">';
    var label1 = '<label>Your&nbsp;Label:&nbsp;</label>';
    var input1 = '<input type="text" name="name" value="foo" />';
    var label2 = '<label>Your&nbsp;Second&nbsp;Label:&nbsp;</label>';
    var input2 = '<input type="text" name="email" value="foo@moo.com" />';
    var sub = '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
    var killform = '</form>';
    var br = '<br />';

    $('body').append(form + label1+input1 + br + label2+input2 + br + sub + killform);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I make it reusable? Let's suppose that I need multiple instances of this form across the site and I don't want to redo the HTML. let's say if I call var $getForm = $(function(){ ...., can I do it this way? I mean is that the correct way in practice

Comment: Well, here's an example (expanding answer).

Comment: I can't really take it much further than here though, as you didn't provide `code` to start with (hence the flood of downvotes). Should be a good jumping off point though. Hopefully you could consider this an `accepted answer` for the question asked. If so, feel free to use the `green checkbox` next to the voting arrows.

Comment: Thanks I am closer to getting the gist of this. Can you check my code above?